# Child interface with same method than parent

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

If interface B extends interface A, and provides a same method as interface A does that mean that method ovewrite the other method?

**Edit**: changed the word *implements* to *extend* since that is wrong and actually didn't mean to write implement hehe...

The purpose of this example code that I found on my exam was to know how the extending between interfaces work and what was asked here was to provide the body of the ConcreteClass, specifically what methods must the class implement: the solution is in the body of the class but what I don't understand is what happens to the methodY(String z) in the Interface_Y, does it get overwriten by methodX(String x) in Interface_Z, shouldn't methodY(String z) be also on the list of the methods that ConcreteClass must implement or does the name of the method not matter when it comes to the possibility of being overwritten?

```
interface Interface_X{
    public int methodX(int x);
}

interface Interface_Y extends Interface_X{
    public void methodY(String z);
    public int methodX(int y);
}

interface Interface_Z extends Interface_X{
    public void methodX(String x);
    public int methodX(int y);
}

abstract class AbstractClass implements Interface_Z, Runnable{
    public abstract int methodX();
    public int methodX(int c) {
        return 0;    
    } 
}

public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass{

    @Override
    public void run(){

    }

    @Override
    public int methodX(){
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void methodX(String z){

    }
}
```

Comment: Override, not overwrite. But yes. The new overrides the old.

Comment: Just as a minor note. An interface can not **implement** another, what you mean is called **extend**.

Comment: "*but what I don't understand is what happens to the `methodY(String z)` in the `Interface_Y`, does it get overwriten by `methodX(String x)` in `Interface_Z`*" - Those are two different methods, neither overrides the other. In order for a method to be overridden, the signature (i.e. name and parameter types) must be equal. --- A remark on the code: In Java, class- enum- and interface-names are written in [UpperCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (`Interface_X` -> InterfaceX`)

Comment: @Turing85 then why doesn't the ConcreteClass require the methodY() of Interface_Y.

Comment: Look at @khachik answer, which explains why.

Comment: @DA because, [as explained by khachik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59910816/4216641), `ConcreteClass` does not implement `Interface_Y`.

Comment: thank you all had a slow wifi and didn't see the answer by @khachik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but what I don't understand is what happens to the methodY(String z)

Nothing happens to it because `Interface_Y` where that method belongs is not in the type hierarchy of `ConcreteClass`.

```
        Interface_X 
       /           \             Runnable
Interface_Y   Interface_Z           /
                     \             /
                AbstractClass     /
                       \         /
                      ConcreteClass
```

Answer (score -1):

Interfaces are just contracts or skeletons. Please see this.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

First of all: An interface never implements an interface. It always extends it.

If a nonabstract class implements two interfaces having a method with the same signature. It must give the implementation for the same by contract. Else the compiler will complain.

Ans to your question?  What happens to methodY of Interface_Y?

Any nonabstract class that implements this interface needs to provide the implementation.